# IIS 7.5 regex matching

Tags: regex, iis

I have the following regex pattern defined in IIS:

```
^_scriptresource(/.*)?$
```

I tested it using the following url:

> ScriptResource.axd?d=J6HwZCiV8u5aE2ZpUKoZZcfboKK4xnSS6qpi8eCNjAXj92WVMSfa_Wr-CKexd2SYXTVes81dsGsKHClg1o9uj6nbuZg76cCdNa-ZV1ThULe45LLGS2K9vGf8y0Xvkgt4fm0EUPgkh8ExKZBISmOm-dv4wD81&t=ffffffffb868b5f4

The point is that the tester that is included in IIS rewrite engine gives a positive match in `{R0}` (which contains the whole url), but when trying to access the url, I can see the following:

```
Request Diagnostics for http://xxxxxxxxx:80/ScriptResource.axd?d=J6HwZCiV8u5aE2ZpUKoZZcfboKK4xnSS6qpi8eCNjAXj92WVMSfa_Wr-CKexd2SYXTVes81dsGsKHClg1o9uj6nbuZg76cCdNa-ZV1ThULe45LLGS2K9vGf8y0Xvkgt4fm0EUPgkh8ExKZBISmOm-dv4wD81&t=ffffffffb868b5f4

OldUrl /ScriptResource.axd?d=J6HwZCiV8u5aE2ZpUKoZZcfboKK4xnSS6qpi8eCNjAXj92WVMSfa_Wr-CKexd2SYXTVes81dsGsKHClg1o9uj6nbuZg76cCdNa-ZV1ThULe45LLGS2K9vGf8y0Xvkgt4fm0EUPgkh8ExKZBISmOm-dv4wD81&t=ffffffffb868b5f4 
NewUrl http://yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy/ScriptResource.axd
```

So far, it seems that IIS rewrite regex engine is removing everything after .axd (starting with the ? character).

I have been testing some combinations of regex patterns but all of them give me the same result.
What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What is the the rewrite URL you provided to IIS?

Comment: Well, that's because the question mark is not at the end, it shouldn't get captured (I'm talking about the `?$` part).